# Why does Future.onSuccess require a partial function

Tags: scala, future, concurrent.futures

I am trying to chain together some basic functions using `Future`s returned from a slick action and I'm hitting some pretty trivial stumbling blocks.

Both the `andThen` and `onSuccess` methods require a `PartialFunction` passed as a parameter. My understanding is probably quite flawed but after reading about [anonymous functions](http://danielwestheide.com/blog/2012/12/12/the-neophytes-guide-to-scala-part-4-pattern-matching-anonymous-functions.html) it seems like `andThen` needs to know your anonymous function with cater for any `Success` or `Failure` input.

Given `onSuccess` already only caters for the `Success` case why does it still need to be a `PartialFunction`?

This block of code my indicate the problem I am having:

```
val db = Database.forConfig("h2mem1")

try {
  val f = db.run(setupCommands)
    .onSuccess { println(_) }

  Await.ready(f, 10.seconds )
}
finally db.close
```

I get a compile error:

```
[error]  found   : Unit => Unit
[error]  required: PartialFunction[Unit,?]
[error]         .onSuccess { println(_) }
```

Comment: @cmbaxter That's `onComplete`, not `onSuccess`. My guess: consistency with `onFailure`.

Comment: 2.11.6 - These [docs](http://www.scala-lang.org/files/archive/nightly/docs/library/index.html#scala.concurrent.Future) suggest PartialFunction?

Comment: I think the better question is why does `onComplete` not also take a partial function?  I think the other 3 were put in place with side effecting with conditions in mind and PFs are good for the conditions part (pattern matching).  I'm just not sure why `onComplete` (also appears to be for side effecting given `Unit` as return type) didn't follow suit.

Comment: I'm not too familiar with the term "side effecting" but the [docs](http://docs.scala-lang.org/overviews/core/futures.html) suggest that andThen and onSuccess are for this. The difference seems to be that they return another Future so that they can be chained together.

Comment: Sorry, onComplete, onSuccess and onFailure all return Unit, andThen returns a Future.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

They did it so you can pattern match on the result, though I agree that it seems needless, I don't really use `onSuccess` and prefer to `map` and `flatMap` my futures:

```
  val f = Future.successful("test")

  f.onSuccess({
    case "test" => println("Worked")
    case x: String => println(s"Kind of worked: $x")
  })
```

In the case of more advanced data types I could see this being more useful:

```
  val fOpt = Future.successful(Option("Test"))

  fOpt.onSuccess({
    case Some(x) => println(x)
    case None => println("None")
  })
```

Really this is probably just coming from the actor api since when you `ask` an actor you don't know the return type, you need to pattern match on it since it's `Any`:

```
  val actor:ActorRef = ???

  val fAny = actor ? "asking"

  fAny.onSuccess({
    case x:String => println(s"Something String $x")
    case x:Int => println(s"Something Int $x")
    case x => println(s"Something else $x")
  })
```

Comment: Though, you can use the pattern matching syntax for regular functions, too.

Comment: @Owen: Yeah, that's what puzzles me too. If I want to pattern match/pass a partial function, I can just do that at any time. Why do we ever need PartialFunction as an argument type?

Answer (score 1):

Well, you can just pass it a `PartialFunction`, if it needs one:

```
db.run(setupCommands).onSuccess(PartialFunction(println))
```

Or:

```
db.run(setupCommands).onSuccess { case result => println(result) }
```

Comment: It just kind of feels needlessly inelegant... I'm sure there is a reason I'm not seeing